# Option literal vs. Option variable

Tags: scala, referential

can anyone explain the behaviour of this snippet:

```
def test = {
  val xt: Option[String] = Some("1")
  val xx: String = "2"
  xt match {
    case Some(xx) => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
  xt match {
    case Some("2") => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
}
```

The Result is

```
match
noMatch
```

Why is there a difference when I change the val against the string literal ?

Comment: You are shadowing the variable `xx`, your first `Some(xx)` is not translated to `Some("2")` but to `Some(someVariable)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `case Some(xx)` doesn't match against the value of `xx` which is in scope, but rather matches *anything* and binds that result to a new variable called `xx`, shadowing the outer definition.

If you want to match against the existing variable, either use backticks:

```
def test = {
  val xt: Option[String] = Some("1")
  val xx: String = "2"
  xt match {
    case Some(`xx`) => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
  xt match {
    case Some("2") => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
}
```

or rename the variable to start with an uppercase letter:

```
def test = {
  val xt: Option[String] = Some("1")
  val Xx: String = "2"
  xt match {
    case Some(Xx) => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
  xt match {
    case Some("2") => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
}
```

*edit*: This is referred to as [Stable Identifier Pattern](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns) defined in §8.1.5 in the Scala language specification

Comment: Those are some interesting gotcha's...!